# How do I attach multiple output console to a running node js app

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to attach multiple instances of consoles to a node js app ?

Is something like this achievable ? I wish the outputs are printed in different windows. Currently using Windows 10

```
let console1 = new Console();
let console2 = new Console();

console1.log("msg to first console");
console2.log("msg to 2nd console");
```

Comment: Not sure how to do this from Node.js, but if you can call the Windows API somehow, it's definitely doable.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

Comment: I could be completely wrong, but you could make a socket server, and have each console connect to that server...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn That would be a real roundabout way to go.  At that point, it would be better just to have child processes.

Comment: @이호남 You'll probably have to make a native module.  If you do that, you can call whatever APIs you need.  https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html

Comment: Well I think the socket server way would be more affordable for me.. since i kinda get the idea. writing a native module seems like so much more to learn. Thank you both.